# Global navigation across all site collections (SharePoint Foundation 2013)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am using SharePoint Foundation 2013.  I would like to have multiple site collections in different content databases for performance, scalability, etc.  I want to have the same global navigation across all site collections.  I know this is trivial in paid versions, but my research hasn't been fruitful.  Recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Delegate control in your master page to deliver the navigation.  Deploy it with a Feature to each site collection.  Write the code in the control to deliver whatever you want, however you want.  Use caching to maintain performance.

Easy, peasy.

Comment: I'm not a SharePoint developer and I need a little more guidance.  Do you recommend any sites that explain the process in more detail?